# Jenkins Pipeline - stage with when and input

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I created a pipeline that has a stage that should execute only when on develop branch. That stage also needs user input. Why does it get stuck on user input for those steps even if I'm on different branch? When I provide input they get skipped correctly.

```
stage('Deploy to UAT') {
    when {
        branch 'develop'
        beforeAgent true
    }
    options {
        timeout(time: 5, unit: 'MINUTES') 
    }
    input {
        message "Deploy to UAT?"
        ok "Yes"
    }

    steps { echo "deploing!" }

}
```

Jenkins version with BlueOceas is 1.7.0  · Core 2.121.1  · d7cda7a  · 13th July 2018 06:49 PM

Comment: should not happen without `beforeAgent true`, does it?

Comment: It does. I added it, trying to fix it.

Comment: how is branch set here?

Comment: not sure what You mean. pipeline is triggered for every pull request (${BRANCH_NAME} becomes PR-XXX) and commit to branch 'develop'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-50785) in the Jenkins pipeline. The `input` step is evaluated before the `when` condition.

Comment: _The stage will pause after any options have been applied, and before entering the stage's agent or evaluating its when condition. If the input is approved, the stage will then continue._ cit. Jenkins User Documentation, Pipeline Syntax [link](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#input)

Answer (score 3):

I recently faced a similar situation and stumbled over the `beforeInput` flag in `when()`:

```
when {
    beforeInput true
    branch 'develop'
}
```

In the [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) you can find additional information:

> By default, the when condition for a stage will not be evaluated before the input, if one is defined. However, this can be changed by specifying the beforeInput option within the when block. If beforeInput is set to true, the when condition will be evaluated first, and the input will only be entered if the when condition evaluates to true.